# Permit "." and "-" in mod rewrite?

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Quick question guys!

I have a Mod_rewrite rule that states that the immediate after my domain directory is a username (I have other rules before this, but this one is the last rule):

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-z]+)/?$ index.php?type=profile&user=$1 [L]
```

So for example: **domain.com/roger** will take my to roger's profile.

However, I am using Facebook Login and realized that some users have "." and "-" signs in their username.

How can I adapt the following expression to support these characters?

```
([0-9a-z]+)/?$
```

Thanks a million!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your regex a bit by allowing dot and hyphen in character class:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-z.-]+)/?$ index.php?type=profile&user=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Note that you will need 2 `RewriteCond` conditions to avoid rewriting for valid files and valid directories as inclusion of dot will cause it to loop otherwise.